# Understanding interest

Tags: algebra-precalculus

You have \$1 billion in a checking account earning .02 interest yearly. You spend \$1000 every day. How do you express the rate at which your money grows?

Comment: Have you tried to do it yourself yet? Show what you did and explain why you couldn't go further.

Comment: How frequently is the interest paid? Without this not sure it can be answered.

Comment: Interest is paid yearly...

Comment: Obviously Y=100000000(1.02)^X with Y being the amount and X being the time in years. I just don't know how to subtract the amount within the equation.

Comment: @Jacob Warner what you have written is not necessarily correct. The annual interest rate could be $0.02%$ but the calculation depends upon how frequently it is compounded. Could be monthly/ daily weekly? The question does not say.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not well written.
I would approach it in the following way:

$
Yearly-interest = 0.02
$

$
Daily-interest = 0.02/360
$

$
Initial-amount = 1,000,000,000
$

$
Amount-day-1 = 1,000,000,000 * (1+0.02/360) - 1,000
$

$
Amount-day-2 = Amount-day-1 * (1+0.02/360) - 1,000
$

So, continue with these recurrence equations up to day 360.

If this approach is not correct, ask your bank manager for more details.